# Custom C# Class Name from JSON

Tags: c#, json, winrt-xaml, datacontractjsonserializer

I have some JSON that nicely deserializes (with DataContractJsonSerializer) to:

```
class Datum { /* properties */ }
```

Is there a decoration (in WinRT) to trick the Serializer?

Something like this:

```
[DataContract(Name="Datum")]
class Hamburger { /* properties */ }
```

Unfortunately that does not work.

I just want a Hamburger class, not a "Datum" class.

Possible?

Comment: Answering your own question in the question makes others go wtf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well [DataContract(Name="Datum")] is the right answer. What appears to be my problem is that once you use [DataContract] you need to use [DataMember] on all the properties. Otherwise, all the properties are null after it is deserialized.